# See files other than home folder files in activity overview seach bar in debian

Tags: debian, gnome

Right now I could only see the applications (frequent and all) and files in the home folder. But I can't see a file which is present in a folder in home directory.

For example I can't see the files in `Downloads` folder in home directory but can see the folder `Downloads` and files present in home directory while searching in the Debian activity overview search bar (latest GNOME version).

Also I am using Linux Mint 16 but the desktop environment I'm using is GNOME with mutter as window manager.